# js toggle: making an anchor trigger a toggle in a different page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, toggle, anchor

So I have 2 different toggles,  when you click on 'info 1' and then click 'link 1' (this would make it go to another page of the site) I want this to trigger toggle 'info 2' to open up for more info, but I can't figure this out..

(in this example i added both toggles on the same page but originally should be separate)

http://jsfiddle.net/qef9zvt4/2/

html:

SECTION 1

```
<ul class="accordion-media-types">
<li>
    <a href="">Info 1</a>
    <div class="hidden-content">
        content
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="">link 1</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

SECTION 2

```
    <!-- THIS WOULD BE IN A DIFFERENT PAGE -->



<ul class="accordionListing">
<li>
    <div class="accordion-heading">
        <a href="">Info 2</a>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion-info section_22">
        content
    </div>
</li>
```

js:

```
//SECTION 1
$(document).on('click', '.accordion-media-types > li > a', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$(this).closest('li').toggleClass('active').find('.hidden-content').slideToggle(500);
});


//SECTION 2

$(document).on('click', '.accordionListing > li > div > a', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$(this).closest('li').toggleClass('active').find('.accordion-info').slideToggle(500);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you exactly trying to do?
Open the second div when you click the link?

Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qef9zvt4/9/

You can just add

```
$(document).on('click', '.accordion-media-types > li > div > ul > li > a', function (e) {
    $(".accordionListing > li > div > a").trigger("click");
});
```

If it was in another page, can't you use document.ready to open the div?
Or does it need to open only when on the first page, the link is clicked?

Comment: Thank you!, that's exactly what I wanted to do, it needs to open up only when on the first page the link is clicked :) thanks!